# Rails: truncate text input instead of whining it's too big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 6.0.21 application which, like any normal application, accepts input from users.

Sometimes users type in by mistake or intentionally very long strings where not really supposed to, eg a random 9348913 character string in an input meant for email addresses which saves in a varchar(255) column.

When this happens Rails errors out:

```
Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'email'
```

I'm looking for a way for the framework to just truncate the data rather than whining it's too big and doesn't fit in.

I can't just truncate before_commit because some models have a lot of fields, I'd end up writing a few thousand lines of code to do this very simple thing.

Anyone know how to do it "automagically"?

Comment: You could just override the setter method for the email column in the model?

Comment: I have like 80 models and a total of like 600 varchar columns of various length. I'd very much like not to have to do it for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the length of the attribute in your model

```
class User
  validates :email, length: { maximum: 255 }
  #validates_lenght_of :email, :maximum => 255 #rails3
end
```

In your view, limits the amount they can enter with the maximum length attribute:

```
<input maxlength="255".... >....
```

And if you have many fields build an array with all the attributes of type string, and if you want to customize the message you can also:

```
class User
  ATTR_TO_VALIDATE = Todo.attribute_names.reject{|attr| Todo.columns_hash[attr].type != :string}
  validates ATTR_TO_VALIDATE, length: { maximum: 255,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks but like I said I have a lot of inputs and columns and I do not want to spend the next 12 days doing this. Besides, if a limit changes later I'll have to dig through all files. I am looking for a simple way to accomplish this.

Comment: I made an update to my answer, but just as long as the length is variable it will not work for you, I have not seen a method on rails that allow you to do what you want. I will be watching if there is any other answer, I'm curious about the solution

Comment: The only thing I can think of so that your code doesn't break is that you change MySQL settings to non-strict mode, that will truncate data that is too long without throwing an error.

Comment: @NickM I think I can create a custom validation (accessible for all models), but you still need to add at least one validation on each model. Tell me if you are interested, so I can build it...

Comment: No Jesus, don't worry about it... gotta find something quicker to implement. Currently playing with a global validator inside ApplicationRecord, it looks promising.